# expected &mut {unknown}, found &PgConnection when using diesel

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Today I upgrade my diesel from 1.4.8 to 2.0.0, when I upgrade the query code like this:

```
pub fn find_sub_org_cte_impl(root_menus: &Vec<Org>) -> Vec<OrgResponse>{
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let cte_query_sub_menus = "sql command";
    let cte_menus = sql_query(cte_query_sub_menus)
        .load::<Org>(&get_conn())
        .expect("Error find menu resource");
    return convert_org_to_tree(root_menus, &cte_menus);
}
```

the `get_conn` show error:

```
mismatched types
expected mutable reference `&mut _`
           found reference `&diesel::PgConnection`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
org_service.rs(29, 10): arguments to this function are incorrect
mod.rs(1497, 8): associated function defined here
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is my `get_conn` function defined:

```
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use rust_wheel::config::db::config;

pub fn get_conn() -> PgConnection{
    let mut connection = config::establish_connection();
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to query after upgrading Diesel to v2](/q/74960545/2189130). Try `&mut get_conn()`.

Comment: Just try: `pub fn get_conn() -> PgConnection {
    config::establish_connection()
}
`